# создане проекта selenide-testng-allure

Tags: allure

Здравстрвуйте, кто-то может помочь с pom-файлом под проект selenide-testng-allure? Т.к. я нашел на гите, но после прохождения теста пишет что репорт сломан..

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй, у меня эта помка работает отлично!! Если что пиши

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <reportVersion>2.6.0</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```